# How to develop a SMS client for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20

my original title was `How to customize TTMessageController for SMS transmission?`. I changed this now because I look for any possible solution and not only those with [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php).

Well, I am working on an simple application in xcode4. The user should be able to send SMS from **different SMS gateways**.

The background logic is quite simple because everything is managed by executing some http requests on an rest api.

The hard thing for me now is to **setup the UI** and that is where I need help because I am new to iOS development. This is how I want it to be:

http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/3159/bhrfe.png

There should be a **recipient picker** to either do autosearch on contacts or to directly pick a contact from the contact list. Beside I want **only one** recipient. And there should be a text area.

I also want to have a label somewhere at the bottom to show the current char number.

Since I did not find those UI elements in xcode4 library I searched for something similar and I found the [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) which gives me the view you see in the picture.

However plus button does not work and I am not sure how to extend all this to do what I want.

**I appreciate any idea on this.**

Comment: By "SMS Gateway" do you mean different SMSCs or a remote API?

Comment: I have a sms server running, I can send sms by doing http requests with different parameters e.g. the gateway type

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but I think it's quite likely it will get rejected from the App Store, if that's the route you were planning to take. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Hm interesting suggestion. This should be clear before I invest more time in this project...

Comment: There are apps on the app store that sends sms from a gateway. WhatsApp sends an sms from a gateway to confirm the phone number you entered. Whether the app will be rejected in the end is up to Apple, but I think there is a good chance it won't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the + Button you can use the address book UI:

```
// This Code is taken from Apple's sample code QuickContacts
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

-(void)showPeoplePickerController {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
    NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];


    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
    // Show the picker 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];   
}
```

The `<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>` delegate include this methods:

```
– peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:
– peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:
– peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
```

After selecting a person you can save his/her number in an array and in the text field (e.g. comma separated)

.

For the question if it will be approved here is the guideline:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

> 22.6 Apps that enable anonymous or prank phone calls or SMS/MMS messaging will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `TTMessageController` to send sms. The only possible way to send sms is to use `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Here's a tutorial on how to use it: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

Comment: thanks, but I want to send the sms from my own gateway. Can I customize how to send the SMS using MFMessageComposeViewController?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, Well, that's a different story. As far as I know there isn't much you can change about the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. You're probably better of modifying the `TTMessageController`. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with `TTMessageController`, so I'm afraid I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, Just out of curiosity: Are you planning on giving away free sms to your users?

Comment: well the user can switch between gateways, some of them ofer free sms. There is no documentation on TTMessageController...:(

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, I know, that's true for most of three20. You need to browse the source code to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. It wasn't clear at the time of this answer that he was going to send the sms through a gateway. Take a look at the revision history or just read the above comments.