# Will Apple reject my iOS SMS client?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Before I go on with my work and put more time in it I want to know if Apple will reject it.

[I am working on a SMS client for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424039/how-to-develop-a-sms-client-for-ios), that is a simple app with three views.

**A settings view**

- the user has to register on my website and optain an appkey
- with this appkey the users account is linked to the app and he is able to send SMS
- the user can choose between different transmission gateways, which are different in price/sms.

**Dashboard**

- the current credit amount of the user is displayed on the dashboard

**Send SMS**

- this view is quite similar to the iPhone SMS view.

I heard their might be a problem with this kind of applications. What do you think?

Comment: Interesting question. Check out [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-store) please, if you develop for any part of the mobile space that has an App market, store or central portal for distribution of apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are apps on the app store that sends sms from a gateway. WhatsApp sends an sms from a gateway to confirm the phone number you entered. You could do a similar thing to authenticate the user and then the sms sending will not be anonymous.

Whether the app will be rejected in the end is up to Apple, but I think there is a good chance it won't be. However, I wouldn't be surprised if it was rejected anyway.

**EDIT:** This is how WhatsApp's authentication works.

1. User enters phone number.
2. Phone number is sent to server.
3. Server sends an sms with a 3 (or 4, don't remember) digit code to that number.
4. User enters the code.
5. Code is sent to server.
6. Code is validated and if it matches the user is authenticated.

I have no affiliation with WhatsApp, but I'd still recommend you to download it, to get a better understanding of how it works. If anything is unclear, ask and I'll try to explain it to you.

Comment: can you describe the confirmation a little bit more. So I just enter my phonenumber which is then validated on a server and I get a response sms?

Comment: We do a similar thing: the user has to register on our website and optain an appkey to use the app. Or must it be the phone numper that should be authenticated?

Comment: I think you're gonna have to use that users phone number when you send the sms. Otherwise you would just use the site to buy an account to send anonymous sms. You could use the website to authenticate the phone number, but I think you'll have to authenticate the phone number some way.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in you other post, Apple is really clear about that. They will not approve an application which supports anonymous SMS messaging:

Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

> 22.6 Apps that enable anonymous or prank phone calls or SMS/MMS messaging
>   will be rejected

Comment: the best way is to write a short email to the approval team and ask them if they would accept it. Point to your website and explain how your service is saved against anonymity and maybe they will made an exception.

Comment: I found an application that is similar to mine in the appstore, cherry sms allows anonymous sms, it's even in the description "any forwarder name"

Comment: ok strange but who knows what they thought at that time. So the best would be to ask apple. And the other question you should ask yourself: What major feature of your application distances you from the other app? Why should your customers buy/use your App and not the other one? You know how many crap application out on the App Store which does all the same or nearly the same.

Comment: I don't want make this a feature discussion ;) thanks for your help, could you please edit your post and remove the //edit stuff, so that people do not think it's not worth to give ideas.